# How to plot the graph of this expression which involves dirac delta function?

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions, dirac-delta, electromagnetism

I Was Doing a Problem on Electrostatics which required finding the charge density from the given electric field and then plot a graph of the charge density. I was able to find the charge density which is
$$\rho=\frac{-Abε}{r^2}e^{-br}+4πεAδ(r)$$
but was not able plot it. When i looked the solution i was not able to understand it.

[image: the solution]

The reason for my confusion is the point r=0 where the left term is minus infinity and the right term is plus infinity. Can any one help me?

Comment: Actually, i want to understand why at r=0 the charge density is 4πεAδ(r).

Comment: Cross-posted to Physics SE: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/437839/